# How to Create Dynamic Columns in SSRS Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to create a **SSRS report like**[image]

And I have table with 3 columns
**DeveloperName,TimeWorked, Date**

How can I create the report and what would be sql query to fetch data? I am not asking for complete SQL query I just need some hints.

Comment: You can use Matrices , Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149.aspx

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot have dynamic columns (check other answers in SO about this). I have once seen a solution for rendering many columns and then hiding some of them. For example, render the 31 columns and match them. Then if there is not data for column `Day31` (because the month has 30 days only) then hide the column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Matrix (instead of tab-lix) to generate dynamic columns. There is no changes required in your sql query for matrix report (its just a list of DeveloperName,TimeWorked, Date) , but the Matrix control in the SSRS will handle all this. You can refer the below inks
http://ssrstutorials.blogspot.in/2012/10/lesson-15-ssrs-matrix-reports.html
 or 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149.aspx