# How can i add columns dynamically in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, rdlc

As I have started working on SSRS report, I came up with a requirement where few columns needs to be rendered depending on the result set i get.

Imagine a user has subscribed to Insurance plan , and depending the plan he opted he may get different Groups.

```
    `User        Name     Valid    Group1      Group2    Group3    Group4  `
 ________________________________________________________________________
     1           Luther    X         X                                  
     2           Lynn                             X                      
     3           Wolfe               x                                     
     4           Jenny     x                                          x
```

If you see above Groups may vary for every Insurance plan. I can get the max number of Groups from my database. For now i am some what successful in by hard coding all Groups . But it is not perfect since with the current approach i will be showing all groups even my plan contains only max Group of 4. Is there way in ssrs where i can generated header columns dynamically.

My result set query is very simple:

```
SELECT USER
     ,NAME
     ,Valid
     ,Opted_GROUP
     ,MaxGroups
     FROM tblInsurancePlans  WHERE InsurancePlanId = @PlanId
```

It would be helpful if anyone has faces this kind of requirement, Please help me on this.

Comment: No .. Max groups can be some times 5 , some times they may go up to 10  as well.

Answer (score 0):

using aggregation:

```
select user,
    name,
    max(valid),
    max(case when opted_group = 'Group1' then 'X' end) group1,
    max(case when opted_group = 'Group2' then 'X' end) group2,
    max(case when opted_group = 'Group3' then 'X' end) group3,
    max(case when opted_group = 'Group4' then 'X' end) group4,
    . . .
from tblInsurancePlans
where InsurancePlanId = @PlanId
group by user,
    name
```

The above requires that you know how many groups there are going to be. If you have dynamic no. of group, you'll either need dynamic SQL or preferably, handle it in application code itself.

Comment: My requirment is to generate a ssrs report with the dataset, it is not hard task to handle it in application , but since i need this result set to generate ssrs Report its going to be somewhat tricky. i need something like this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130747/how-to-create-dynamic-columns-in-ssrs-report?rq=1, let me try this once