# Adding Child Records to New Columns Instead of New Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Each ID can have many repeated rows as showing the first table to the left, the requirement is to place 'child' records of the same ID on the same row and repeat the column headers as showing below in the table on the right.

I am trying to do this in SQL Server, here is my attempt at it:

```
if Object_id('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
Begin
 drop table #temp1
End
create table #temp1 (
    ID integer, FirstName varchar(50), LastName varchar(50)
)
insert into #temp1 values (25,'Abby','Mathews');
insert into #temp1 values (25,'Jennifer','Edwards');
insert into #temp1 values (26,'Peter','Williams');
insert into #temp1 values (27,'John','Jacobs');
insert into #temp1 values (27,'Mark','Scott');

Select * From #temp1;

With Qrt_CTE (ID, FirstName, LastName)
AS   
(
  SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName 
  FROM #temp1 AS BaseQry
)
SELECT ID, ColumnName, ColumnValue INTO #temp2
FROM Qrt_CTE
UNPIVOT
(
    ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN (FirstName, LastName)
) AS UnPivotExample

Select * From #temp2
```

[image: SQLTableLayout]

How do I get these results done please?

Thank you so much in advance, appreciate any help.

Comment: This is an action that is better to do in the report presentation software -- not in SQL.  To do it in SQL you would have to use dynamic SQL unless you know the maximum number of repeats in the ID column.

Comment: Do you always have at most 2 repeated IDs or can this vary?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using SSRS, is it possible to have done on the reporting side? If yes, I need a simple example that can help me, would you be able to share an example, please?

Comment: thank you, Stu, no, the repeated IDs can be anything.

Comment: Yes -- SSRS is a reporting tool -- it is possible to do in SSRS

Comment: The SQL language **does not work this way**, as this would be in direct opposition to the relational set theory underpinning SQL databases.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn -- I'd go so far to say use cases don't work this way -- I can't think of an example where you want a report with an unbounded number of columns.

Comment: Hogan, can you give me a simple example or a pointer on how to do it in SSRS please?

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: How to do dynamic columns in SSRS was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130747/how-to-create-dynamic-columns-in-ssrs-report

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Hogan Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it, was able to create a matrix report that would group on each column name to produce the needed report, however the second row starts at the column after the first row's columns end, is there a better way to make all rows start at the first column please?

Comment: I've no idea @Franko -- I've never written an SSRS report -- did you try google?  or the product documentation?

Comment: The order of the new column pairs is by `FirstName` from left to right according to your sample data. Is that a requirement? Is there any order requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot a number of columns with a conditional aggregation

```
select 
   id
   ,max(case rn when 1 then FirstName end) FirstName1
   ,max(case rn when 1 then LastName end) LastName1
   ,max(case rn when 2 then FirstName end) FirstName2
   ,max(case rn when 2 then LastName end) LastName2
  -- ..
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by FirstName ) rn
  from #temp1) t
group by id
;
```

Comment: This only works if at max there are two names -- he says there can be any number.

Comment: @Hogan, in any case, this only works if the number of rows with the same ID is less than half the limit on the number of columns.

Comment: Ok,  but the OP still said he wants it to be unlimited -- you got to make it dynamic to solve the problem.

Comment: You do know that 2016 was 7 years ago?  You might want get a version that is less than 5 years old.

Answer (score 1):

If what you actually want is a list of all users with an id -- (a common use case) then you should do that this way

```
SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(FirstName + ' ' + LastName, ', ') as Names
FROM #temp1
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using -- it is documented right here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Maybe you are using DB2 or Oracle?  Then use LIST_AGG

Comment: 2016. however, if it can be done on SSRS, could you provide an simple example please?

Comment: @Franko -- see comment above -- this is a basic SSRS feature called Matrix reports

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving you the full source-code, this is a large-ish work, but I will provide the steps that you will need to get through

## Find out the number of columns

You will need a variable, I will call it `cnt` which will hold the result of `select max(count(1))` from your table, grouped by `ID`.

## Before you loop until `cnt` with an index

- Initialize `selectClause` as `ID, t1.FirstName as FirstName, t1.LastName as LastName`
- Initialize `fromClause` as `from yourtable t1`
- Initialize your index to 2 (we already handled the first `t1`)

**For each steps:**

### Append the selection:

Append `, t<i>.FirstName as FirstName, t<i>.LastName as LastName` to `selectClause`, where `<i>` is your current index value (replace it with the actual index name). You can use `CONCAT` to concatenate variables and text chunks and you can convert integers into numbers in several ways, see this for an example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

### Append the table

Append  `left join yourtable t<i> on t<i-1>.ID = t<i>.ID and CONCAT(t<i-1>.FirstName, t<i-1>.LastName) < CONCAT(t<i>.FirstName, t<i>.LastName)` to `fromClause`

### Increment the index

Don't forget to do it :)

## Once the loop completed

Concatenate `selectClause` and  `fromClause` and don't forget to append  `group by ID` to your concatenation. Now your query is ready.

## Run the dynamic query

You can do that with [EXEC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) or [sp_executesql](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

## Dangers

- beware SQL injection, your text data could be dangerous, see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp
- this is arduous and labor intensive

Comment: Why is there no SQL code? 
Why are linking to w3schools -- one of the worse sites on the internet?

Comment: @Hogan I think that based on my answer anyone can figure out a solution. And it's better to avoid writing the code for being too long than writing code which has little to do with the problem, such as your code, which does not have the multiple `FirstName`/`LastName` columns the op asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for responding to my question.
I was able to resolve it by creating an SSRS matrix report and grouping on the rows (ID) and the grouping on the columns (all other columns needed to be part of the group).
Thanks to @Hogan for suggesting the SSRS reporting idea.

[image: Here is how it looks like]